# Spring Boot i18n in multi modules project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, internationalization, application.properties

I have this multi modules project:

```
Parent Pom
|
|----Main module (@SpringBootApplcation and application.properties)
|
|----Module I
|
|----Module II
|
|----Module III
```

The main module depends on other modules and contains `messages.properties` and `messages_fr.properties` under `resources/messages/` and also the `application.properties` where I defined `MessageResource` bean `spring.messages.basename=messages/messages`.
Now I would like to put the `messages.properties` files in each module. Eg for Module I, under `src/main/resources/messages/messages.properties` same thing for Module II. 
My question is, how can I add the module's messages in the `MessageResource` bean defined in `application.properties`? 
I tried several declarations like these:

`spring.messages.basename=messages/messages,classpath:/com/company/moduleI/resources/messages/messages` or `spring.messages.basename=messages/messages,classpath:moduleI/resources/messages/messages` but none works. 
Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: By default Maven copies the content of a `resource` folder to the root of class path. Have you tried `classpath:messages/messages`?

Comment: @KenBekov I've just tried it but same result

Comment: Check if this file exists in the root classpath (`target`). If it isn't then you can use Maven assembly plugin in order to copy (and rename) files from dependency modules.

Comment: @KenBekov When I looked inside the main module .jar all other modules are in its `lib` folder. Resources files of each module are on the root of the module's classpath. I will take a look on that Maven assembly plugin. I'll let you know. Thanks for this hint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found a better solution, using the `ResourceBundleMessageSource#addBasenames(...)` to add all modules' messages.

**EDIT**

In each module, I renamed the message files, e.g. for Module I, I had `resources/messages/moduleI-messages.properties`, `resources/messages/moduleI-messages_en.properties`.
Then I defined a configuration class in that module to add the messages source files.

```
@Configuration
public class ModuleConfig {
    private final ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource;

    @PostConstruct
    public void addMessageBaseName() {
        messageSource.addBasenames( "messages/module1-messages" );
    }
}
```

I am sure there could be a better way to go but I didn't find it.

Comment: what strings did you pass to `addBasenames` to get this to work?